# React + i18next + Trans + Prettier: Prettier eventually destroys translations when reformatting JSX

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier, i18next

I have a react project using i18next for translations. My Visual Studio Code also runs "Prettier" to make my code look more beautiful :-)

In some cases I need to use the `<Trans>` component in order to be able to translate texts containing HTML/JSX markup

So this works perfectly:

```
<Trans i18nKey="msg_new_user_register">
  New user - please <Link to="/register">register</Link>
</Trans>
```

with this in `translation.json`

```
"msg_new_user_register": "New user - please <1>register</1>",
```

But now I needed to add the `state` property to the `Link`. After doing this, Prettier strikes back and reformats the string to

```
<Trans i18nKey="msg_new_user_register">
  New user - please{" "}
  <Link
    to="/register"
    state={
      location.state
        ? { from: { pathname: location.state.from.pathname } }
        : null
    }
  >
    register
  </Link>
</Trans>
```

even though I wrote everything in one line. In this case, the translation is only showing the text before the `Link` and the `Link` itself is completely ignored.

Is there any way to work around? Can Prettier be specifically asked to ignore JSX "one-liners" when reformatting?

Can i18next `Trans` be made more tolerant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out myself ...

`<Trans>` has an alternative way of stating the default value (other than using the children):

```
<Trans
  i18nKey="msg_new_user_register"
  defaults="New user - please <mylink>register</mylink>"
  components={{
    mylink: (
      <Link
        to="/register"
        state={
          location.state
            ? { from: { pathname: location.state.from.pathname } }
            : null
        }
      >
        DUMMY
      </Link>
    ),
  }}
/>
```

with this in translation.json:

```
"msg_new_user_register": "New user - please <mylink>register</mylink>",
```

It will show the rendered element no matter how Prettier reformats it.